# R: Copy matrix triangles, excluding NA values

Tags: r, matrix, copy, na

I have a large matrix structured as follows:

```
m = structure(c(NA,9,NA,NA,NA,
                NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                10,7,NA,12,11,
                9,7,NA,NA,11,
                10,8,NA,NA,NA),
              .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
```

I need to copy values only (excluding NA's) from the upper triangle to the lower triangle, and vice versa, to get a matrix that looks like this:

```
m.result = structure(c(NA,9,10,9,10,
                9,NA,7,7,8,
                10,7,NA,12,11,
                9,7,12,NA,11,
                10,8,11,11,NA),
              .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I think you mean upper and lower _triangle_ (not diagonal). ;)

Comment: yes, lower triangle!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with help from Ronak's answer:

```
m1 = structure(c(NA,9,NA,NA,NA,
                 NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                 10,7,NA,12,11,
                 9,7,NA,NA,11,
                 10,8,NA,NA,NA),
               .Dim = c(5L, 5L))

m1[lt] <- ifelse(is.na(lowerTriangle(m1, byrow=FALSE)), upperTriangle(m1, byrow=TRUE), lowerTriangle(m1, byrow=FALSE))
upperTriangle(m1) <- lowerTriangle(m1, byrow=TRUE)

m.result = structure(c(NA,9,10,9,10,
                       9,NA,7,7,8,
                       10,7,NA,12,11,
                       9,7,12,NA,11,
                       10,8,11,11,NA),
                     .Dim = c(5L, 5L))

identical(m1,m.result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
lt <- lower.tri(m1)
ut <- upper.tri(m1)

m[lt] <- coalesce(m[lt], m[ut])
m[ut] <- coalesce(m[ut], m[lt])
```

---

Or with `ifelse` keeping it in base R :

```
m1[lt] <- ifelse(is.na(m1[lt]), m1[ut], m1[lt])
m1[ut] <- ifelse(is.na(m1[ut]), m1[lt], m1[ut])
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not giving the correct output matrix, but good idea to use the ifelse statement in base R. I figured it out using that function, code posted! Thanks again!

Comment: I think it's just a typo. Replace `m1` with `m`. ;)